# Cannot find name of exported Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, module

I am having an issue exporting an interface... 
I have defined it like so in my-config.ts:

```
export interface MyConfig{
  useTitleSuffix: boolean;
  defaults: {};
}
```

and I am exporting it like so in index.ts

```
export { MyConfig} from './my-config';
export { MyService } from './my.service';
export { MyModule } from './my.module';
```

When I import this in another module like this:

```
import { MyConfig, MyModule } from 'my-module';
```

then MyService and MyModule will be found, MyConfig though isn't. "Cannot find name 'MyConfig'"...

Anybody having an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that your path is correct? It seem it must be export *{ MyConfig} from './my.config';*

Comment: path is definitely correct...

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry that I cannot comment yet so I wrote this as an answer)
Assuming that all the file names are correct, the only real possibility I can think of is a typo in the usage of the interface.

A full error (i.e, from tsc) with the corresponding line could help lock down the issue.

Also, if this is an IDE error, then know that VSCode tends to show these when you create a new file.